# Картинки из api в picturebox или datagrid view

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, picturebox

Имеется API newsapi.org. Создаю запрос, получаю JSON ответ. В нем есть поля urlToImage. В общем, хочу вставить картинку из этой ссылки, в dataGridView. Нужна помощь с последовательностью действий, остальное попробую сам додумать (Надеюсь, правильно описал суть вопроса)
Пишу программу на c# WindowsForms, пользуюсь библиотекой newtonsoft.Json

Да, знаю про DataGridViewImageColumn, но дело в том, что у меня датагрид, по сути, создается автоматически.

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = newsList;
```

Поэтому, как настроить свойства столбцов я пока не знаю...

Comment: [DataGridViewImageColumn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn)

Comment: Самый простой способ загрузки изображения по URL, видимо, использовать [PictureBox.Load](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.load). Пикчабокс при этом не нужно помещать на форму. Забрать изображение из свойства `PictureBox.Image`.

Comment: Использование привязки данных никак не мешает добавлять столбцы вручную.